# Converting variadic template to variadic function

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, variadic-templates, variadic-functions

Given the following case:

```
#include <iostream>

enum class Event { None, Resize, /*Some Other Events*/ };

template<Event Type, typename...>
struct validator;

template<Event Type>
using eventor = typename validator<Type>::type;

template<>
struct validator<Event::Resize> { using type = void(*)(unsigned int, unsigned int); };

struct My_Event {
    unsigned int size;
    void** funcs;
    const Event &m_ev;

    My_Event(const Event &ev, void(*f)(...)) : m_ev(ev), size(1), funcs(new void*[size]) { *funcs = f; }

    void reg(void(*f)(...));
};

struct EventHolder {
    unsigned int size;
    My_Event** events;

    EventHolder() : size(0), events((My_Event**)malloc(size)) {}

    void add(const Event& ev, void(*f)(...)) {
        My_Event** eventDump = (My_Event**)(malloc(size+1));
        memcpy(eventDump, events, size);
        *(eventDump + size) = new My_Event(ev, f);
        free(events);
        events = eventDump;
    }
};

struct EventRegistry {
    EventHolder holder;
    void registerEvent(Event&& ev, void(*f)(...)) { holder.add(ev, f); }
} events;

template<Event Type>
void registerEvent(eventor<Type> f) {
    events.registerEvent(Type, f);
}

void callback(unsigned int width, unsigned int height) {}

int main() {
    registerEvent<Event::Resize>(callback);
}
```

Which it's throwing errors of kind:
`'void foo1(SomeEnum &&,void (__cdecl *)(...))': cannot convert argument 2 from 'void (__cdecl *)(unsigned int,unsigned int)' to 'void (__cdecl *)(...)`

(The main point here is registrating events as shown in `main`, and having an `My_Event` array in `EventHolder`)

If I make the global function `registerEvent` a variadic function, it will force all callbacks to ve variadic, which it's not what I'm looking for

If I make EventRegistry's registerEvent a variadic template, let´s say

`template <typename ...Args> registerEvent(Event&& ev, void(*f)(Args...));`

Then EventHolder's `add` should accept also variadic templates, which will turn it into:

`template <typename ...Args> add(const Event& ev, void(*f)(Args...));`

As EventHolder's `add` invokes `new My_Event(ev, f)`, then `My_Event`'s constructor should also be variadic. As that constructor stores stores the functions in an array locally, the whole struct `My_Event` should be variadic **<sup>1</sup>**, but if the whole struct is variadic, then I can't store it in `EventHolder`'s array (storing a base class won't work as all methods used in `My_Event` would depend on the template too.

**<sup>1</sup>** When writting this, I realized this statement is wrong (thanks to @Igor comment). I stored all functions in `My_Event` just like `void` pointers, and made all member functions which accessed the list (including the constructor) variadic templates. After doing so, I could make all other functions variadic templates and it *compiled*

This question is solved. Can't accept [Igor's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48362569/converting-variadic-template-to-variadic-function?noredirect=2#comment83714481_48362569) as it's a comment, not sure how to mark this question as solved or close it

Comment: That code won't generate that error message.  Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: `template <typename ... Args> void registerEvent(Event&& ev, void(*f)(Args...)) {...}`      or `template <typename F> void registerEvent(Event&& ev, F&& f) {...}`

Comment: `void(*f)(...)` doesn't mean "accept any function type", it means "accept a pointer to variadic function". `callback` is not a variadic function.

Comment: Ikr what it means, but I can do none of your suggested approaches because adding a template to EventRegistry's registerEvent would mean storing a list of templates later (a base class won't work as the template affects behavior on used functions), which is not possible in c++. Isn't there a way on treating callback as an specialization of a variadic function? Or to specialize variadic functions at all? Will add an update with more relevant details as soon as I get to a computer

Comment: In C++, names beginning with an underscore immediately followed by an uppercase letter, are reserved for the implementation.

Comment: @Juan ask IgorTandetnik to post his comment as an answer and if he doesn't do that in reasonable time then post yourself the answer and accept it.